# Angular test failing : "Expected a spy, but got Function."

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, spy

I have this test, perfectly running:

```
it('The click on the logo must call goTo("home")', () => {
  spyOn<LayoutComponent, any>(component, 'goTo');
  let logo = fixture.debugElement.query(
    By.css('#logoVitisoft')
  ).nativeElement;
  logo.click();
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    expect(component.goTo).toHaveBeenCalledWith('home');
  });
});
```

And this one (which is barely the same than the previous one) triggering the error :

```
it('The click on Dashboard must call goTo(home)', () => {
  spyOn<LayoutComponent, any>(component, 'goTo');
  let button = fixture.debugElement.query(
    By.css('#dashboardElem')
  ).nativeElement;
  button.click();
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    expect(component.goTo).toHaveBeenCalledWith('home'); /* ERROR SPAWN HERE */
  });
});
```

Precisions : both tests passed if they are called with "fit", I have disabled the randomness of the test and I keep executing ng test with the same seed. The error spawn when I call the 2nd test as "it" : "Expected a spy, but got Function."

EDIT : here are the beforeEach

```
beforeEach(async () => {
 await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpClientModule],
  declarations: [LayoutComponent],
 }).compileComponents();
});
beforeEach(() => {
 fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LayoutComponent);
 component = fixture.componentInstance;
 fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: can you show `beforeEach`es and `beforeAll`s?

Comment: Yes sorry, I added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fixture.whenStable()` returns a Promise, which is asynchronously executed. This means your test is already finished and cleaned up when `expect()` is executed.

Try using the `done()` function for these kinds of tests:

```
it('The click on Dashboard must call goTo(home)', (done) => {
  spyOn<LayoutComponent, any>(component, 'goTo');
  let button = fixture.debugElement.query(
    By.css('#dashboardElem')
  ).nativeElement;
  button.click();
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    expect(component.goTo).toHaveBeenCalledWith('home');
    done();
  });
});
```

Comment: Works just fine ! Thank you very much !

Comment: You're welcome :) I would appreciate if you mark this as the accepted answer 